# Spring Batch - HibernateItemWriter : Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port

Tags: hibernate, azure-sql-database, spring-batch, azure-sql-server

I have a Spring Batch application that uses HibernateItemWriter to update the Azure SQL Server database.

The batch job gets executed for 20mins and failed with the following error

> Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire
> JDBC connection

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP
> connection to the host
> sqlsrv-01.database.windows.net, port 1433 has
> failed. Error: "sqlsrv-01.database.windows.net:
> Temporary failure in name resolution. Verify the connection
> properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the
> host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP
> connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

Below is my implementation

```
public class StoreWriter implements ItemWriter<List<Store>> {

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StoreWriter.class);

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void write(List<? extends List<Store>> items) throws Exception {
    HibernateItemWriter<Store> hibernateItemWriter = new HibernateItemWriter<>();
    hibernateItemWriter.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

    for (List<Store> Store : items) {

        hibernateItemWriter.write(Store);

    }
    hibernateItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
    logger.info(String.format("Store Processing Completed %s", new LocalDateTime()));
}}
```

I guess it is a temporary issue however I want to know if I can implement a retry logic to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StoreWriter` does not add any value over the `HibernateItemWriter`. You  could use the `HibernateItemWriter` directly in your step.

This `StoreWriter` creates a new `HibernateItemWriter` for each chunk, which is not efficient and could be the root cause of your issue (ie a new session is created for each chunk, and at some point, it is not possible to acquire a new session anymore, hence the error `Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction`). The delegate writer should be refactored as a field, something like:

```
public class StoreWriter implements ItemWriter<List<Store>> {

   Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StoreWriter.class);

   private HibernateItemWriter<Store> hibernateItemWriter;

   public StoreWriter(HibernateItemWriter<Store> hibernateItemWriter) {
      this.hibernateItemWriter = hibernateItemWriter;
   }

   @Override
   public void write(List<? extends List<Store>> items) throws Exception {
      for (List<Store> Store : items) {
        hibernateItemWriter.write(Store);
      }
      logger.info(String.format("Store Processing Completed %s", new LocalDateTime()));
   }
}
```

Comment: how do we pass the 'hibernateItemWriter' to 'StoreWriter' bean especially with 'sessionFactory' object?